# Zend Framework helpers path problem

Tags: zend-framework, helper

```
 [2] fopen(/var/www/vhosts/tuthost/httpdocs/application/controllers/helpers/ViewRenderer.php)  failed to open stream: No such file or directory 
  in file: /var/www/vhosts/tuthost/httpdocs/library/Zend/Loader.php 
  on line: 165 
  [2] fopen(/var/www/vhosts/tuthost/httpdocs/application/views/helpers/HeadTitle.php)  failed to open stream: No such file or directory 
  in file: /var/www/vhosts/tuthost/httpdocs/library/Zend/Loader.php 
  on line: 165 
  [2] fopen(/var/www/vhosts/tuthost/httpdocs/application/views/helpers/FormLabel.php)  failed to open stream: No such file or directory 
  in file: /var/www/vhosts/tuthost/httpdocs/library/Zend/Loader.php 
  on line: 165 
  [2] fopen(/var/www/vhosts/tuthost/httpdocs/application/views/helpers/FormSelect.php)  failed to open stream: No such file or directory 
  in file: /var/www/vhosts/tuthost/httpdocs/library/Zend/Loader.php 
  on line: 165 
  [2] fopen(/var/www/vhosts/tuthost/httpdocs/application/views/helpers/FormText.php)  failed to open stream: No such file or directory 
  in file: /var/www/vhosts/tuthost/httpdocs/library/Zend/Loader.php 
  on line: 165 
  [2] fopen(/var/www/vhosts/tuthost/httpdocs/application/views/helpers/FormTextarea.php)  failed to open stream: No such file or directory 
  in file: /var/www/vhosts/tuthost/httpdocs/library/Zend/Loader.php 
  on line: 165 
  [2] fopen(/var/www/vhosts/tuthost/httpdocs/application/views/helpers/FormSubmit.php)  failed to open stream: No such file or directory 
  in file: /var/www/vhosts/tuthost/httpdocs/library/Zend/Loader.php 
  on line: 165 
  [2] fopen(/var/www/vhosts/tuthost/httpdocs/application/views/helpers/FormCheckbox.php)  failed to open stream: No such file or directory 
  in file: /var/www/vhosts/tuthost/httpdocs/library/Zend/Loader.php 
  on line: 165 
  [2] fopen(/var/www/vhosts/tuthost/httpdocs/application/views/helpers/HeadStyle.php)  failed to open stream: No such file or directory 
  in file: /var/www/vhosts/tuthost/httpdocs/library/Zend/Loader.php 
  on line: 165 
  [2] fopen(/var/www/vhosts/tuthost/httpdocs/application/views/helpers/Layout.php)  failed to open stream: No such file or directory 
  in file: /var/www/vhosts/tuthost/httpdocs/library/Zend/Loader.php 
  on line: 165
```

What can cause this?

How to fix helpers path to bundled ZF helpers?

At bootstrap i have only this:

```
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/controllers/helpers','Helper');
```

and this:

```
$viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper(
    'ViewRenderer'
);
$viewRenderer->setView($view);

// Return it, so that it can be stored by the bootstrap
return $view;
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335545/how-to-add-a-view-helper-directory-zend-framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to add a view helper directory (zend framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335545/how-to-add-a-view-helper-directory-zend-framework)

Helped this topic.