# Zend Framework path to helpers

Tags: zend-framework

fopen(C:/xampp/htdocs/adv/application/views\helpers/Layout.php) how to fix this path?

And why does ZF is searching for bundled helpers in this folder and not in zend library folder?

By the way, here path is fine, but still searching in wrong folder

fopen(C:/xampp/htdocs/adv/application/controllers/helpers/ViewRenderer.php)

Comment: Ooo sorry. You must be more clear. In the first fopen function you have "\helpers" instead of "/helpers". This is the problem?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335545/how-to-add-a-view-helper-directory-zend-framework/2335588

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZF searches in these paths, because they are the default paths.

From the [ZF Reference Guide on View Helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html)

> **Note: Default Helper Path**
>   The default helper path always points to the Zend Framework view helpers, i.e., 'Zend/View/Helper/'. Even if you call setHelperPath() to overwrite the existing paths, this path will be set to ensure the default helpers work.

The second path is for ActionHelpers (as indicated by ViewRenderer) and is the default path as well. It is hardcoded into [`Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getPluginLoader()`](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Controller/Action/HelperBroker.php).

The ViewHelper path doesn't have to be fixed. PHP knows how to handle directory separators, so it doesn't matter whether is is a slash or a backslash.

See the linked question and answers on how to add additional helper paths.